# Cleaner way to use array_search?

Tags: php

I have the following string after it has been parsed by regex:

```
FOO_BAR_FOOBA_*_R:FOO_*
```

I am supposed to get rid of "FOOBA" so I thought that just by doing, should have been enough.

```
$size[0] = array('qwe', 'rty', 'uiop', 'asdf');
$size[1] = array('ASD' , 'FGHJ' , 'ZXCVB');
$size[2] = array('lol' , 'cat' , 'woof');

$pieces = explode("_",$noGen);

foreach ($size[0] as $value){
$search = array_search($size[0], $pieces);
unset($pieces[$search]);
}
```

However, I know that the code above pretty much would have worked out until I found out that not all the time the third "piece" exists and that the second piece sometimes can contain same values as the third one.

Is there a way to do this without having to use a foreach per size. If it is not clear I could add more information or just ping me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: well im confused, give 5 examples of input strings and desired outputs

Comment: Why not just use `preg_replace()` on the string?